# Python multiprocessing.Process module not using all CPU cores?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm running the following code on windows machine with a powerful inter-core i5 - 12600k processor with 16 cores.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    windows = np.linspace(30,cpu_count()*30,cpu_count()).astype(int)
    significance_level = 0.1
    processes = []
    for window in windows:
        p = Process(target=save_betas_over_window, 
                    args=(assets_historical_returns,
                          factors_historical_returns,
                         ),
                    kwargs={
                        'window':window,
                        'significance_level':0.1
                    }
                   )
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

the code is supposed to run the method `save_betas_over_window` simultaneously for each of the items in the `windows` list. I used `cpu_count` to make the windows list the same length as the number of available CPU-cores on my machine. So, theoretically-as far as I understand-, all the 16 cores should be working. However, when I checked the resource monitor, it shows that only 4 cores [12:15] are used up to 100% while the remaining cores are barely used.

[image: Resource monitor]

my question is, why some cores are used and others not? isn't it supposed that `multiprocessing.Process` module assigns processes to available CPU cores that are not used, and if so, why some cores are used up to 100% while others are not used at all?

I'm new to parallel processing and this is so confusing to me,
Appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: use multiprocessing.Pool(processes=None)  (obviously u can use 16 instead of None)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
The issue was solved by [manually setting the affinity](https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-manually-allocate-cpu-cores-windows-10/) for each process. I assigned one core for each process and now the CPU is working at full capacity.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Multiprocessing module in python
Pool method of Multiprocessing lets you use the number of CPUs

I will show you an example

```
p = Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 2)
p.map(callfunction, val_set)
```

Here,
We have defined the a function named 'callfunction' which takes an argument lets say 'val'

val_set contains data in a set values. Let's say -- {'a', 'b'}

So, here one CPU will call `callfunction(a)`
Other one will call `callfunction(b)`

According to the code I provided, `cpu_count() - 2` will assign a maximum of total cpus - 2 present in the server.